# Java Reflection - Get size of array object

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, size, illegalargumentexception

I was wondering if any knows hows to get the size of an array object using reflection?

I have a **Vehicles** component containing an array object of type **Car**.

**Vehicles.java**

```
public class Vehicles{

    private Car[] cars;

    // Getter and Setters
}
```

**Car.java**

```
public class Car{

    private String type;
    private String make;
    private String model;

    // Getter and Setters
}
```

I was wondering how I would be able to get the size of the **cars** array within the **vehicles** component using Java Reflection?

**I current have the following:**

```
final Field[] fields = vehicles.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

if(fields.length != 0){
    for(Field field : fields){
        if(field.getType().isArray()){
            System.out.println("Array of: " + field.getType());
            System.out.println(" Length: " + Array.getLength(field.getType()));
        }
    }
}
```

which results in the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(Native Method)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

The method `Array.getLength(array)` expects an array instance. In you code sample you are calling it on the array type for the field. It won't work as an array field can accept arrays of any lengths!

The correct code is:

```
Array.getLength(field.get(vehicles))
```

or simpler

```
Array.getLength(vehicles.cars);
```

or simplest

```
vehicles.cars.length
```

Take care of a null `vehicles.cars` value though.

Comment: Well, you might as well say cars.length :-)

Comment: You are right! The original code was so complicated for such a simple thing that I get messed up and kept the reflection...

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you have to pass the array object itself to `Array.getLength()` so try

```
Array.getLength(field.get(vehicles))
```

Comment: `field.get()` on an object which would have that field.

Comment: Sure, have to pass the vehicles object!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
System.out.println(" Length: " + Array.getLength(field.get(vehicles)));
```